# I want to add 30 days to mysql date row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Code.

```
    <?php //data.php
require_once 'db.php'; 

// Get values from form
$Fname       = $_POST['first_name'];
$Lname       = $_POST['last_name']; 
$web         = $_POST['web'];   
$email       = $_POST['email'];
$date        = $_POST['date'];
// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, web, email, date)
VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$web', '$email', '$date', NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$sql="SELECT DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL 30 day)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
header('Location: ../index.php');
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close mysql
mysql_close();
?>
```

My problem, i want to add those 30 days to the date column in database when form execute`s this file and inserts fname in  fname, web in web, and date in date + 30 interval.

Thank you.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, web, email, date)
    VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$web', '$email', '$date', NOW())";
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    ***$sql="SELECT DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL 30 day)"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);***
```

Comment: wanna fetch or update??

Comment: use Shankar Damodaran's query its write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query :

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, web, email, date)
    VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$web', '$email',DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL 30 day)  , NOW())";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this...

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `web`, `email`, `date`)
    VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$web', '$email', DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL 30 DAY))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, web, email, date)
    VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$web', '$email', '$date', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))";

    $result = mysql_query($sql); 

>> you are adding date after query executes, but do the same when query executes.
```

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part you need to change

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, web, email, date)
VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$web', '$email', '$date', NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
```